# What's the lowest level at which a PC can break through a hewn stone wall in 1 round?

Tags: optimization, pathfinder-2e

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162778/is-there-any-way-to-destroy-stone-walls-within-2-rounds) asks how PCs can break a stone wall. Aside from the usage of *disintigrate* to immediately destroy a wall, it seems that a wall can be destroyed by reducing it's HP to 0. Walls have a hardness which reduces the damage done to them.

What is the lowest level at which a player character can destroy a wall in 1 round? Magical and mundane means are both in scope, and any item which the character has access to. Limit items to the character's level or lower.

Comment: How thick of a wall?

Comment: @mxyzplk-JusticeforMonica I don't think it matters. The table on CRB 515 shows hardness and HP, without reference to thickness. I'm looking at the reprinted version on the GM screen right now, but I recall the table being similar in CRB.

Comment: Wall of stone says per 5 feet but whatever...

Comment: @indigochild the hardness may not change but the HP does. So I would dare sy you should clarify how thick the wall should be.

Comment: @ThomasE. Where can I find the details on how HP is related to thickness? The DM screen at least just shows a flat HP based on the material. Thickness is not related.

Comment: @indigochild as far as I understand it the HP is per 5 ft. of thickness. (makes no sense else that 5 ft of steel is as easily to be destroyed as a 1 mile thick steel armor

Comment: Is this assuming no outside assistance? What about buffs?

Comment: @ThomasE. CRB says 5x5 foot - which I had assumed meant 5 feet wide by 5 feet tall. The values are specifically for a stone wall, which sets some practical limitations on the domain of possible values.

Comment: @YogoZuno Sure - so long as it all fits within 1 round!

Comment: @indigochild I think you need to clarify your assumptions a little there. What about precast buffs? Are we assuming a particular party size or composition? Magic items?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a way to do this at first level with some assumptions:

1. A [stone wall](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=730) has 56 hp with hardness 14
2. One can [critically](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=222) [succeed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=196) at [attacking a wall](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=675)
3. One rolls maximum on all damage dice
4. One can use a first level consumable

A fighter wielding a greatpick with 18 strength, with the power attack feat and using a potency crystal.

damage breakdown:

- [Greatpick](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=23)  has a d10 damage die but has [fatal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=178) (d12) which makes a crit deal 3d12
- [Power Attack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=359) adds 1 damage die to a strike (2 on a crit)
- [Potency Crystal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=231) adds 1 damage die to a hit (2 on a crit)
- 4 from strength mod (double to 8 on a crit)
- 3d12+2d12+2d12+8 = 92 damage

Comment: are you sure about fatal getting crits to 3d12 and not only 2d12? (not sure on how to interpret the fatal text)

Comment: @ThomasE. Deadly adds an extra die on a crit of a specific size. Fatal increases the base die, and adds another die. 3d12 is correct for a crit with a greatpick.

Comment: @CaptianObvious Interestingly, I cannot find any concrete proof that an attack roll is still required to attack an inanimate object. If not, it might well be impossible to Crit.

Comment: Action to rage seems inefficient given the assumptions listed for this answer. +4 damage is far less than an extra attack would supply, which removes the need for level 2.

This response is good for the slightly different, but still interesting question: 'What is the lowest level at which a player can destroy a wall in 1 attack'.

Comment: @Isaac good catch, not sure why I didn't think of hitting it a second time, but that second hit would also need to be a crit to bypass the 14 hardness as a greatpick with 18 strength only deals a max of 14, however a potency crystal (lvl 1 consumable) adds another damage die to an attack and would make this work at 1st level and in a single hit. Will edit when I find the time if someone doesn't beat me to it

Comment: interestingly this almost doable at first level without maximum damage dice with 2 crits and a potency crystal: Attack 1(Power attack): 7d12+8 = 53.5; Attack 2: 3d12+8=27.5; this leads to a total of 81 expected damage over 2 attacks. since there were 2 attacks we need to account for hardness twice giving the wall an effective hp of 84 (56+14+14) making this just 3 damage shy of doing it. Scraping power attack for 3 attacks still does not work ((5d12+8) + (3d12+8) + (3d12+8))=95.5 vs a 3 hit wall with 98 effective hp

Comment: @YogoZuno, did some digging best ruling I could find was the section for attacking hazards: https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=675, this seemed to indicate that you can attack a hazard and logically if you attack it you can make an attack roll and thus can critically succeed, but that is probably up to GM interpenetration

Comment: @YogZuno, further digging on object immunities, no mention of crits: https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=196

Comment: @CaptianObvious Nice find, but still not proof you can crit...note in the section on Hazards 'A hazard that doesn’t list one of these statistics can’t be affected by anything targeting that statistic.'